# how could i use final in text value?

Tags: flutter, dart

In some cases, programmers mark a text value as a `final`, does that mean that you can not change its value?

**Sample of code:**

```
final String textValue=" ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, A `final` variable can be set only once.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const

Note: Although a final object cannot be modified, its fields can be changed. In comparison, a const object and its fields cannot be changed: they’re immutable.

Comment: what is the exact meaning of its fields ?

Comment: A `final` object cannot be reassigned/rebound to another object.  `final` does not prevent the object from being *mutated*.  Note that Dart `String`s are immutable, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `late final` which introduced in Flutter 2.0, which allows us to set final value at runtime, but only once

```
late final int value;
value = 5; 
print(value); // Working
value = 6;//Error: The late final local variable is already assigned.
          // Value will be assigned only once.
```